# Speeding up QGIS Processing - Plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, performance

I am trying to calculate the angular integration and angular choice of a nationwide road network (Line SHP).

PST does the job, however it uses ALL (and by that I mean 100%) of my CPU's cores, but does not seem to get anything done. It is projected to take 100s of hours to get the task done.

PST Plugin - https://github.com/SMoG-Chalmers/PST/tree/master

A few questions, is it possible to speed up the process within QGIS?

Although it seems unlikely as it already uses the full processing potential of my machine, maybe I'm missing something out?

If the above seems unlikely, would there be a way to run the same process outside of the QGIS environment, possibly on a compute engine?

My limited knowledge tells me that this requires decoupling the plugin itself - not a single clue how this works.

Comment: Some hints : https://github.com/SMoG-Chalmers/PST/issues/4 . I advise you to post an issue on the plugin repo instead of asking here a solution.